# Mongodb lookup aggreagation with subquery

Tags: mongodb, meteor

So I am performing a mongodb query where I actually perform a join
with a subquery in it.

Stack: MeteorJs: 2.8/mongodb > 4.4

I have 2 collections: customers (around 60000 documents) and sales (around 50000 docs).

What I'm trying to do is performing an aggregation to get the customers and joining the sales to it.

A customer document look like the following:

```
{
  _id,
  name,
  ...
}
```

A sale document looks like this:

```
{
   _id,
   customerIds : [<arrayOfCustomers>]
}
```

As you might have guessed, I try to join to sales that contains the customer _id in its customerIds array.

The pipeline looks like this:

```
const pipeline = [
{
  $match: {...}
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'sales',
    let: { customerId: '$_id' },
    as: 'sales',
    pipeline: [
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $in: ['$$customerId', '$customerIds'] }
        }
      },
    ]
  }
}];

const customers = await Customers.rawCollection().aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
```

Actually the pipeline and the lookup works fine but in extremely (like extremely) slow (more than 20 sec)

And if I do a simple lookup without the pipeline, it become "normal" again (1.5 sec)

I mean I am feeding the pipeline so I get less sales documents to retrieve but the opposite
is happening.

Could it be that internally Mongodb is increasing the roundtrip the get the right sales ?
Every collection has the right indexes regarding the performances so it's not about indexes actually.

What is your opinion on that ?

Thanks a lot for you help !

Comment: Do you have an index on clustomerIds in the sales collection?

Comment: Hello ! Indeed I have. In that case it's customerIds index that I need and have regarding this line  $expr: { $in: ['$$customerId', '$customerIds'] } :)

Comment: Try using explain to see why it is slow